# Why are the words poison and poisson so similar?

Tags: étymologie

I recently discovered that the words poison and poisson, meaning poison and fish in English are very similar, despite not being contextually even close. Might it be that fish might rot and become poisonous? I haven't found anything that might even suggest an answer.

Comment: it's just a coincidence. Another example would be **cousin** (cousin) and **coussin** (pillow/cushion), but there are even more "SS vs S" in French like **base** (base) and **basse** (bass) or **case** and **casse** etc. It is the case with other letters aswell.

Comment: For another example with a different pair of voiced-vs-unvoiced consonants, **vin** (wine) vs **fin** (end).

Comment: When I read "poisson" in English, I think of the [French mathematician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sim%C3%A9on_Denis_Poisson), or the [probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) (useful in modeling arrival times etc.) named after him (which is just one of several concepts named after him).

Comment: These words are so similar for the very same reason bitch and beach are.

Comment: I think it is closer to the difference between **biter** and **bitter** in English

Comment: @MorganFR Not really, **biter** and **bitter** are similar because they are related, eventually sharing the proto Indo-European root *bheid- "to split". See http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bitter

Comment: An example working both in french and in engligh (with or without e acute): **désert** and **dessert**.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would say this is accidental.

The word 'poisson' comes from the Latin *piscem*, meaning fish, while 'poison' comes from 'potion' which itself originates from *potio*, also Latin but meaning beverage.